# systemd timer OnCalendar always starting next day

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemd, archlinux-arm

I want to poweroff my raspberry pi (running Arch ARM) every day at 5 pm. So I created the following service and timer:

poweroff.service:

```
[Unit]                                                                  
Description=poweroff service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/poweroff
```

poweroff.timer:

```
[Unit]                            
Description=poweroff timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 17:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

If I check systemctl list-timers (executed today at 8 am), I get:

```
NEXT                        LEFT          LAST                       PASSED      UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Fr 2016-03-18 17:00:00 CET  1 day 9h left n/a                        n/a         poweroff.timer               poweroff.service
```

And that is the problem. This Service never runs since its always aiming for the next day at 5 pm and not the current day. Did I miss a settings to tell OnCalendar that it should aim for 5 pm today? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a bug: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2682. Should be fixed in a future release.